# I am trying to integrate v2 of LUIS api in my node.js bot but it's not working

Tags: node.js, botframework, azure-language-understanding

The following code works fine with LUIS v1 but not working with v2.

Any one know the update to/work with v2?

```
        var bot = new builder.UniversalBot(connector);
         server.post('/api/messages', connector.listen()); 
          var recognizer = new builder.LuisRecognizer('https://api.projectoxford.ai/luis/v2.0/apps/956c-4784-a26d-b7fb3e00df7b?subscription-key=492514272a354088915b56321');
              var intents = new builder.IntentDialog({ recognizers: [recognizer] });
                                            bot.dialog('/', intents);

               intents.matches('TSUGGEST', [
                      function (session, args, next) {
                       var task = builder.EntityRecognizer.findEntity(args.entities);
              var task1=builder.EntityRecognizer.findEntity(args.entities,'builtin.number');
        if (!task1) {
                  builder.Prompts.text(session, "Please tell article name");

                     } 

          else {
      next({ response: task1.entity });
           }
      },
      function (session, results) {
         if (results.response) {
        // ... save task
           session.send("Ok... '%s' task.", results.response);
           } else {
         session.send("Ok");
               }
               }]);
```

Comment: I add the same issue, I finally decided to keep using the v1 API for now.

Comment: I just updated the answer with the instructions to use the prerelease version of the builder which contains a fix

Answer (score 2):

It seems they added support to v2 on Node.js a few days ago, per [this commit](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/commit/caa1db9174d3c7a422b3aa1f601a23f59d0566b9) to the master branch; however that's not yet published as npm package.

You might have to get the library from the GitHub repository and try using that instead of the package published; or you can use the prelease version of the builder by doing:

```
npm install --save botbuilder@next
```

This was discussed [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/issues/1633).

Answer (score 2):

after contact with ms team, it is really a bug. a quick workaround is to add "&verbose=true" at the end of luis v2 endpoint